# Objective-c image loading problem. Problem is relative/absolut path

Tags: objective-c, path, relative-path

I'm trying to show an image to the screen but the provider

provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(filename);

doesn't create correctly if I give the relative path of the image:

All classes are in project/Classes/   and  ball.png is in project/

if I write: "/Volumes/SAGITTER/Lavoro/Progetti xCode/IVBricker test/ball.png"

I have http://img412.imageshack.us/i/schermata20110217a15482.png/

so provide is correctly created.

If I write "ball.png" I have http://img43.imageshack.us/i/schermata20110217a15484.png/

How can I solve?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the path to the image. Include it in your application bundle and use `NSBundle` to retrieve the path.

Comment: I red the official doc but I still don't understand what NSBundle does in simple terms...

Comment: Did you read the [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/)?